# Issue running Azure Monitor Log Analytics query using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor

I am trying to run the below log analytics query using Azure CLI. I have created the workspace required. However, I am getting the error as below. I have upgraded my CLI version to the latest one based on google recommendations but nothing seems to have worked so far. I have also ensured the workspace ID is the same as the one in Azure Workspace.

```bash
az monitor log-analytics -query -w xxxxxx --analytics-query "Perf | where ObjectName == 'LogicalDisk' "
```

'xxxxxx' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

The eventual outcome I am looking for is to get a list of all VMs in all the subscriptions and their used disk space ( not the allocated disk space ).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when I tried in my environment. So, I modified a bit and executed as below:

```
az monitor log-analytics query --analytics-query "Perf | where (ObjectName == 'LogicalDisk')" -w <workspace-ID>
```

[image]

Error is disappeared, but empty block is being retrieved. So, there is a need to upgrade the CLI & python versions to the latest releases. However, running the *"upgrade"* command in CLI shows that it is still in development.

[image]

I found an alternative to run azure Monitor Log Analytics query using "*Kql query inside workspace logs"*:

```
Perf | where (ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes") | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer | sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

[image]

*Reference:*
[MsDoc to check log queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-performance-counters#log-queries-with-performance-records)